# How can I get a list of encodings that Perl 6 understands?

Tags: encoding, raku

I see in */src/core/Rakudo/Internals.pm* a hash with a short list of encodings but no way to get to it outside of that. The `NORMALIZE_ENCODING` method is the only thing that uses it. Use something that is not in this list and you get an exception.

So, how can I know what's valid before I try it, especially since some important encodings are missing?

```
my $encodings := nqp::hash(
      # fast mapping for identicals
      'utf8',            'utf8',
      'utf16',           'utf16',
      'utf32',           'utf32',
      'ascii',           'ascii',
      'iso-8859-1',      'iso-8859-1',
      'windows-1252',    'windows-1252',
      # with dash
      'utf-8',           'utf8',
      'utf-16',          'utf16',
      'utf-32',          'utf32',
      # according to http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1
      'iso_8859-1:1987', 'iso-8859-1',
      'iso_8859-1',      'iso-8859-1',
      'iso-ir-100',      'iso-8859-1',
      'latin1',          'iso-8859-1',
      'latin-1',         'iso-8859-1',
      'csisolatin1',     'iso-8859-1',
      'l1',              'iso-8859-1',
      'ibm819',          'iso-8859-1',
      'cp819',           'iso-8859-1',
    );
    method NORMALIZE_ENCODING(Str:D \encoding) {
        my str $key = nqp::unbox_s(encoding);
        if nqp::existskey($encodings,$key) {
            nqp::atkey($encodings,$key)
        }
        else {
            my str $lc = nqp::lc($key);
            nqp::existskey($encodings,$lc)
              ?? nqp::atkey($encodings,$lc)
              !! nqp::lc($key)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The whole encodings handling in Perl 6 is still provisional AFAIK – see e.g. jnthn's discussion of his plans for user-space encodings, [starting here](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-09-21#i_13250951) in the IRC logs.  
So I wouldn't be surprised if there's really no way to query for supported encodings yet.

Comment: could you point out some important encodings that would be worth implementing even before the user-space encoding stuff goes in?

Comment: UTF-16 would be really nice.

Comment: This is fixed now. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Question is from 2017: does anyone have an update?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your original question: there does not seem to be such a thing. However, the code for encodings has changed, and now you can [register new encodings and check existing ones; those list also available encodings](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/646f9211cf6589ba646d6c71586ef8e7f6b0b209/src/core/Encoding/Registry.pm6#L12-L22).

There's also a function, `find`, that returns an encoding object if it exists:

```
say Encoding::Registry.find('oh-no'); 
# OUTPUT: «(exit code 1) Unknown string encoding 'oh-no'␤»
say Encoding::Registry.find('latin1'); 
#OUTPUT: «Encoding::Builtin.new(name => "iso-8859-1")␤»
```

The corresponding class is now documented.